# Uploadify not passing form data to php page via post

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I am trying to pass multiple image files along with album id to insert.php, but only the file details are passing - but no album id. Grateful if someone can assist on this.

My code is below:  It passes all file data  but not album data to insert.php.
I am using uploadify v2.1.4

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     //alert('I am Ready!');
     $("#file_upload").uploadify({
       'debug'   : true,
       'uploader': 'uploadify.swf',
       'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
       'auto': false,
       'multi' :true,
       'method'  : 'post',
       'postData'  : {},
       'queueSizeLimit' : 10,
       'onQueueFull' : function(event, queueSizeLimit){
        alert(" You can upload " + queueSizeLimit + " files at once");
        return false;
       },
        'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
         var album_id = $("#album_id").val();
         $.post("insert.php", {
            name: fileObj.name, 
            path: fileObj.filePath, 
            size: fileObj.size, 
            album_id:album_id}, 
            function(info){
                alert(info);
            });
       }
   });
});
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form method="post"  action="">
  <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
  <select id="album_id" name="album_id">
  <option value="1">First type</option>
  <option value="2">Second type</option>
  </select>
   <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();">Upload File</a>

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the value from the selected option like this:

```
var album_id = $("#album_id option:selected").val();
```

Also, I think you have a problem with using album_id without quotes as property name in the JSON data.  Try this:

```
$.post("insert.php", { "name": fileObj.name, "path": fileObj.filePath, "size": fileObj.size, "album_id":album_id}, function(info){
```

Comment: Hi Mike, tried your suggested changes but still album id is not passing to insert.php, only size & image id.

Comment: What value do you get for album_id if you log it to console?

Comment: I am getting blank data from uploadify for album_id.

Comment: @AjaySingh I guess my question is, after this line of code `var album_id = $("#album_id").val();` if you insert a console.log statemnet or place a break in your javascript debugger, what value do you get for `album_id`?

Answer (score 0):

try passing the values using 'scriptData'  : {},

```
'scriptData': {'name':'JohnDoe', 'location':'Australia'},
```

not sure if postdata works like scriptdata